# yum enable all repositories

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, yum, openvino

While running a script that install openvino dependencies, I got the following yum error:

There are no enabled repos.
Run `yum repolist all` to see the repos you have.
You can enable repos with `yum-config-manager --enable <repo>`

I found on google and tried the following command, but I still have the same error:

```
sudo yum-config-manager --enable \*
```

I do this on a raspberry pi with: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Comment: Try to add a backslash: `--enable Enable the specified repos (automatically saves). To enable all repositories run "yum-config-manager --enable \*" `

Answer (score -3):

[Installing OpenVINO™ toolkit for Raspbian OS](https://docs.openvino.ai/2021.4/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_raspbian.html) does not require to run the *install_openvino_dependencies.sh* script to install OpenVINO™ dependencies.